# Cordova Splashscreen slide up, instead of fade

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

As of today, one can put a setting of the splashscreen in config.xml - and decide for fade of the splashscreen.

But how is it possible to "slideUp" the splashScreen instead? (or slide down for that matter) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't out of the box, you will need to modify the native code.